# Adding a list to df and getting Error invalid __array_struct__

Tags: python, pandas

Hi so I have a list of 54000 items, some of which say None. I want to add this list as a column to a df that has 54000 rows as well. I think I need to add a N/A to the empty rows but I can't seem to do that.

This one gives me: Error invalid _*array_struct*_

```
df.insert(loc = 0,
          column = 'name',
          value = list)
```

while this gives me: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['name']), ignore_index=True)
```

This is what the first few items in the list print as:
[[40.614479, -73.926401], None, None, [38.851787574468084, -77.32203340425532]]

Comment: Python lists can't be blank, it has to be something. The empty string can look empty. It would help to have a working example. Instead of 54000 items, how about 4 items and a fully working script showing the error?

Comment: Hi thank you. I have added the first few items of the list at the end. The error says "ValueError: invalid __array_struct__"

Comment: The rows do say None in them so that was my mistake. I cannot add the list to df though

Comment: So, its a list of lists, so 2 columns. Except for the `None`. So, pandas is trying to process those inner lists but some are missing. What would be a good default for those numbers? Maybe `fixedlist = [row for row in list if row else [None, None]]`. But you should be able to take that example data and make a working script. You shouldn't expect us to do that for you.

Comment: Ah okay. I failed to recognize the list within a list. I can write a script with that knowledge obviously

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing should be as easy as making the list an additional column in the dataframe:

```
df['new_name'] = the_list
```

Unless there's something very unusual with the list.

Btw I'm assuming you are using a different name for the list than 'list', and this is just an example. If you aren't, you've either overwritten the variable for the function, or are trying to assign the function to the dataframe.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this first and it had the same error of invalid array structure (but thank you and I do have other names ofc)